# Is it possible to output the probability by neural network?

Tags: machine-learning, statistics

Is there a good way to learn the probability of getting 6 out of the dice data?

**I have the following data.(about 100000 records)**

1. Data related to dice (Detailed data such as material, weight, position of center of gravity, number of faces)
2. The result of rolling the dice only once. (6: true, otherwise: false)

All dice are similar but with slightly different feature values.

Example:

```py
{"dice": [12.56344, 4.432556, 5, 32.45566, 1.135566, 142, 2.235555], "result": true}
{"dice": [1.34412, 36.934, 4, 15.2223, 4.55556, 122, 3.3312567], "result": false}
.
.
.
```

What I want to get is **a function** that outputs the probability of getting a 6 when I input the feature of the dice.

f: data -> [0,1]

I tried using genetic programming to generate an equation to predict probabilities, which is very brutal.

I have investigated probabilistic neural networks, but I did not get an understanding of their applicability to such problems.

Please give me a hint. Thank you.

Comment: Couldn't you just use a sigmoid output layer?

Comment: Can it be said that it represents a probability just because the output is [0, 1]?

Comment: In multi class classification, this assumption is made all the time. You assign the probability of 1 to its true output label and 0 for everything else. I don't see it being any different here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer.
I do not know why it is possible to do gradient descent so that NN can output 0.2 as a result of doing BackProp with data of dice that 6 comes out once in 5 times.
Is it because there is "Learning rate decay"? The error never converges. Even if the output converges to 0.2, the error for each data is always 0.2 or 0.8. This is not an optimization problem for each data. Optimization problem for all data.

Comment: When I made an ideal dice for trial and output the probability with Sigmoid, this worked well. [0.16558951] ≒ 1/6

Why···

Comment: However, this did not work very well if the die traits were different on an individual basis.